# Cannot delete a document library

Tags: document-library

I am new to sharepoint, so maybe I am missing something obvious, but I can't delete document library off my sharepoint site for some reason.

I set myself up as the admin of this sharepoint site, and I have "Full Control" on my account, yet when I try to edit a page for a document library and go to delete it...the button is greyed out and I get a tooltip that says "This control is currently disabled" and "You might not have the right permission levels to perform this operation"

With full control being checked, shouldn't I be able to delete the lib?

Am I missing something?

I am running SP2010

**EDIT 2**
I figured it out.  Once I realized I was trying to delete a library (originally I was trying to delete the library page, thinking that was the same) I googled and found this:  http://www.hosting.com/support/sharepoint3/deletedoclib

I am still not sure why deleting libraries is so awkward....but it works and I understand what I was doing wrong now.  Hopefully if any other SP noobs out there run into this they will find it helpful.

Comment: Hi,

If its on the page then probably you are trying to delete the List View Web Part of the document library because deleting a document library is about to go in Library Settings -> Delete this library.

Just check if the page where your list view web part lies is inheriting permission from its parent web, if it is not inheriting then you should add yourself to the page permission.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Default Document library cannot be deleted directly, it has a property that prevent users to do it. You can remove the property with powershell using this [guide](http://sharelockpoint.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/how-to-delete-a-document-library-that-doesn%E2%80%99t-have-a-delete-option/)

> ```
> $web = Get-SPWeb("http://YourSite")
>
> $list = $web.Lists["Documents"]
>
> $list.AllowDeletion = $true
>
> $list.Update()
>
> $list.Delete()
> ```

Comment: It doesn't work