# How to delete a sharepoint document library that doesn’t have a delete option

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I have found few documents library in site collection that doesn’t have a delete option under Permissions and Management !!
  Note : I have migrated these site collections from WSS3.0 to SP2010

Comment: Do they have custom permissions? Have you tried deleting it via SharePoint Designer?

Comment: No .. I don't have any custom Permission

Comment: See this question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61852/cannot-delete-a-document-library